# probability question,interval [0,1] is split to 3 parts by 2 random points X,Y~U[0,1]. X,Y are independent. Z=min' of all 3 parts. find E(Z)

Tags: probability

I am having trouble solving this question. I saw a solution that used a bit of geometry (plotted Y vs. X axis and used areas to found F(z), the CDF of the Min' value) but I want to know if there is another way of approaching questions like this.

$X,Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed $U[0,1]$
.
The interval is splitted to parts $ [X,Y-X,1-Y]$ ...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this can be easily solved using a computer algebra system. For your example, by independence, random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

```
f = 1;   domain[f] = {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}};
```

Then, the solution to your problem can be obtained as a simple one-liner as:

```
Expect[Min[x, y-x, 1-y], f]
```

> -1/9

where `Expect` is a function from the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica*. Similar packages exist for Maple.

If your problem is to show 'all the steps manually', solve the integrals etc as a homework exercise ..., then I am not sure that it is appropriate for others to fulfil that role here. But at least you have the answer to work towards.

---

In response to the suggestion below by robjohn, the `Expect` function (which is part of the `mathStatica` package of which I am one of the authors) calculates symbolic / theoretical solutions to arbitrary expectation problems, given an arbitrary user-specified pdf $f(x)$ - whether continuous, discrete, multivariate or univariate etc, and it does so by taking advantage of a computer algebra system (in this case *Mathematica*). The solutions produced are exact symbolic solutions - not numerical nor approximate. I believe similar functionality exists for Maple (I am not an author of that software). We have received requests to build a version of mathStatica for Maple, but there is no plan to do so at the present time.

Comment: Hi, yes it is a homework question. I have one solution. but I was looking for maybe an easier/trivial way that maybe I have missed...
dont want all the steps manually :) hints will be good...

Comment: As a coauthor of mathStatica, you might want to explain what `Expect` does so that it can be simulated elsewhere.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for the suggestion - added a note to the end. Please note that `Expect` is a symbolic construct - not an approximate simulator.